# SpringBoot no encuentra un bean existente - APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Tags: spring-boot

Llevo ya un montón de horas trabajando en este proyecto de SpringBoot y Siempre recibo un mensaje de error al arrancar.
Os agradeceria si me podeis orientar acerca de donde buscar...yo ya he agotado ideas.

He intentado mostrar solo la informacion relevante, para no aburriros, pero si necesitais mas informacion, solo decirlo.
Como me habeis pedido, la clase boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude ={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan({"rf.com.tienda"})
// EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"rf.com.tienda.repository"})
public class MggTienda2023Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MggTienda2023Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

He ido modificando cosas para realizar distintas pruebas, y la ultima, ha sido pasar a la version 2.7.10 y limpiar el repositorio....pero todo sigue igual; gracias por la ayuda.

Esto es el servicio

```
package rf.com.tienda.servicio;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import rf.com.tienda.dominio.Categoria;
import rf.com.tienda.exception.DomainException;
import rf.com.tienda.repository.CategoriaRepository;

@Service
public class CategoriaService implements ICategoriaService {

    @Autowired
    private CategoriaRepository categoriaRepository;
```

El objeto se encuentra en el package previsto

```
package rf.com.tienda.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import rf.com.tienda.dominio.Categoria;

@Repository
public interface CategoriaRepository extends JpaRepository<Categoria, Long> {

}
```

Sin embargo, siempre recibo el error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field categoriaRepository in rf.com.tienda.servicio.CategoriaService required a bean of type 'rf.com.tienda.repository.CategoriaRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'rf.com.tienda.repository.CategoriaRepository' in your configuration.
```

Todo el aplicativo se encuentra a vuestra entera disposicion en
[Github](https://github.com/recursosformacion/tienda2023-2/tree/main/MGGTienda-2023)

Comment: Quita la anotacion `@Repository` de `CategoriaService`. Como el mismo nombre indica, eso no es un `@Repository`, sino un `@Service`. A un nivel fundamental, es posible que Spring sepa usarlo de todos modos, pero esas extensiones de `@Component` existen por una razon. El error en si mismo me dice que Spring no esta buscando tus componentes en tu paquete `dal` o `repositories`, lo que es tristemente comun en mi experiencia. Por favor, comparte tu clase principal (La anotada con `@SpringBootApplication`).

Answer (score 0):

Parece que este problema, junto al de EntityManager que aparece al activar el @EnableJpaRepository se soluciona utilizando, en mi caso, que trabajo con Java 11, la version de SpringBoot 2.7.10 y borrando el (exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}) que tenia puesto para "solucionar " otro error.